# Iterate over Dictionary: Get 'NoneType" object is not iterable error

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

The function class:

```
def play_best_hand(hand, wordDict):

tempHand = hand.copy()
points = 0
for word in wordDict:
    for letter in word:
        if letter in hand:
            tempHand[letter] = tempHand[letter] - 1 
            if tempHand[letter] < 0:
                return False
            if wordDict[word] > points:
                bestWord == word
                points = wordDict[word]
return bestWord
```

Here is my trackback error.  Line 209 corresponds to the line 'for word in wordDict'

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ps6.py", line 323, in <module>
    play_game(word_list)
  File "ps6.py", line 307, in play_game
    play_hand(hand.copy(), word_list)
  File "ps6.py", line 257, in play_hand
    guess = play_best_hand(hand, wordDict)
  File "ps6.py", line 209, in play_best_hand
    for word in wordDict:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the variable `wordDict` is `None` instead of a dictionary. This means there's an error in the function that calls `play_best_hand`. Probably, you forget to `return` a value in a function, so it returns `None`?

Comment: Got 'er fixed after I started hunting!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the `play_best_hand()` function you have:

```
if wordDict[word] > points:
    bestWord == word
```

You probably meant to do an assignment instead of comparing for equality:

```
if wordDict[word] > points:
    bestWord = word
```

Comment: @Noah Clark: Probably even with this corrected it can happen that `bestword` isn't set to anything before it is returned. (For example it happens if `wordDict` is empty or if `hand` is an empty string.)